# What's wrong of the menu, it can't be horizontal?

Tags: css

Site :http://project-t.businesscatalyst.com/egt.html#

It is a business catalyst hosted site, the framework is bootstrap.  my menu included submenu and this part is ok.  however, I can't make it from vertical to horizontal.  I'm a newbie in HTML/CSS/JS, if you inspect custom.css, I try to add a id and css it "display:inline", I try to control the width of div, but all failed. Could anybody give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 0):

In your css add this code. It will solve your problem.

```
#egt ul li {
  float: left;
 }
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot.  Now i need to handle the hover bg color less than the box.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css in your css file

```
.nav > li > a {
display:inline
}
```

Please let me know if it worked

Comment: It is another method & works.  maybe the text is no padding, the text is located in top i will try to make it a bit lower, thank you.

Comment: If that works, then you can give the upvote.. :P anyway happy to know it worked..